# Firestore PERMISSION_DENIED on Google Cloud Compute

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have a Java application using firebase-admin that I'm trying to get to observe a collection in Firestore and act upon modifications to it.

I have the following code:

```
final GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials
            .getApplicationDefault();

final FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(credentials).setProjectId("XXX")
            .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
```

where "XXX" is a triple-checked ID of my Project.

A little bit later there's this:

```
final ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> future = db.collection("YYY").get();
final List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = future.get().getDocuments();
```

where "YYY" is a name of a collection (I tried running it on both empty and non-empty collection).

Once I build the application I upload it to a Google Compute Engine instance. When I run it, the last line causes the following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:500)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:479)
        at com.google.api.core.AbstractApiFuture.get(AbstractApiFuture.java:56)
        at com.dammitchat.App.main(App.java:55)
```

I have ran the following on the VM:

```
~$ gcloud auth list
                  Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       XXXXXXXXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

I checked IAM and this service account has "Editor" role (just in case, I tried adding "Cloud Datastore Owner" as well), so I would imagine it can bypass any rules I have set for my collection. There is, in fact, a rule for this collection that states:

```
match /YYY/{y} {

    allow read: if false;
}
```

but even when I changed it to `true`, the result was the same.

Now, the odd thing is that when I run the application locally with another "Cloud Datastore Owner" service account it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it reads:

> Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

for `RPC` *one* of these oAuth2 scopes needs to be requested:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud

the service-account authentication is explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers) (that's what the error message hints for).

for security rules (which are not the reason for that error message), see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

also see the [Cloud Firestore API](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/) and the Java [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/firestore).

Comment: Scopes! Thanks for that. Somehow, I totally missed that concept. Works now.